# Spring Boot + Spring Batch : setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders does not work with hybrid app (XML + annotations)

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, annotations

**Background**

I am currently working on migrating a legacy Spring application to Spring Boot and the Microservices architecture. I am breaking down my application into smaller Microservices based on the business functionality and the data they operate on.

My legacy app uses XML configurations and I have now extracted some business functionality from this app into a separate Spring Boot project. There are certain XML Spring configuration files that I cannot move to annotations right away as they belong to another team. This means that my Spring Boot project has to import these XML Spring configuration files until they are moved to Spring Boot themselves.

**Code:**

My main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource(locations = { "classpath:spring/interest-forecasting.xml" })
public class InterestRatesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InterestRatesApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

My Batch Configuration class (Relevant parts only) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job interestRatesDataLoadJob(DataSource dataSource,
            InterestRatesCacheWriter writer,
            ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter argumentPreparedStatementSetter,
            InteresrRatesCahceDataLoadListener listener) {

             //code to assemble to job

    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
        ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(
                transactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }
}
```

**The issue**

The interest-forecasting.xml has a lot of beans that refer to some properties using `${property.name}` syntax which I don't care about in the interest rates microservice. I only need a few beans from this xml file. I thought of overriding the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and added the following code to the main class :

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
```

This results in the following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bfb173 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5
```

1. If I remove the `@ImportResource` and the
   `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, my job runs perfectly fine.
2. If I remove the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` but keep the `@ImportResource` to import my XML spring config, Spring starts complaining about missing properties in the XML config.
3. If I keep both `@ImportResource` to import the XML and  `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` configuration, I get the above exception.

**How can I call setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders in a hybrid Spring Boot application as I don't care about certain beans being loaded with correct properties, specially from the XML bean configuration file which I cannot change?**

**Note :** I have added `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` to my application.properties so that I can override the auto configured beans created by Spring Boot such as using a Map based job repo instead of writing job metadata to the database.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the exception? It has nothing to do with your placeholders.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes. As explained in my question, there are beans in the `interest-forecasting.xml`  config file that fail to load because they refer to some properties using `${property.name}` syntax. I don't care about these beans so I thought of overriding the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` so I can call `setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true)`. It is after adding this `Bean` configuration do I get the `ClassCastException` mentioned in my question. My job works fine if I don't import `interest-forecasting.xml`; however, I need to import this XML for some business logic. Hope that helps?

Comment: If you don't need the beans then don't load them. You will run into issues if you load those (those beans are still instantiated and if requiring something else as an `String` will blow up your application due to casting/conversion exceptions). However as stated your error is not related to placeholders but due to a bean overriding a bean of a different type. I.e. a `JobRepository` with a specif factory-bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't need all the beans from the XML but I do need some beans. That is why I want to `setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true)`. To do this, I override the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` which ends up causing a completely unrelated exception. Can you give me an example where one would be able to override  `JobRepository` with `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` without compilation errors?

Comment: It aren't compilation errors. Also if you don't need beans don't load them. Extract the beans you need in a new configuration and load that. You don't want to load stuff that isn't needed, that will lead you to different errors in the future.

Comment: @M.Deinum I explained in my question that I don't control the source code for the XML configuration : * "There are certain XML Spring configuration files that I cannot move to annotations right away as they belong to another team..."* . I don't maintain the codebase containing the XML configuration. It is a  Black Box such that all I should be knowing about the XML are the names of the beans I can use. These are the non technical limitations I have so I can't copy these beans to my XML. I'd rather use the beans I need and suppress the property config for the rest..